# Icon Angular2 as images

Tags: angular

Good Morning
I have a side menu in which I want to put the icons, and I want to put images downloads for me.
My code is:

```
path: 'pages',
    children: [
      {
       path: 'ganado',
       data: {
          menu: {
            title: 'Ganado',
            icon: '../assets/icon/ganado.png',
            selected: false,
            expanded: false,
            order: 1
          }
       }
     },
    {
      path: 'confort',
      data: {
          menu: {
            title: 'Confort',
            icon: 'ion-home',
            selected: false,
            expanded: false,
            order: 2
          }
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'calidad',
      data: {
          menu: {
            title: 'Calidad y Composción',
            icon: 'ion-erlenmeyer-flask',
            selected: false,
            expanded: false,
            order: 3
          }
      }
    },
```

If I put icons like 'ion-home' or 'ion-erlenmeyer-flask' it shows the icons well, however if I want to use a custom image does not show it to me.

Upload image so you can see the result.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnGU0.png)

What can I do to display the png image I have in assets?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I modified the question